# Flutter I am using widget Error:Only static members can be accessed in initializers

Tags: android, dart, flutter

I need to access templist from ImagePreviewPage StatefulWidget in _ImagePreviewPageState. But it is showing *Only static members can be accessed in initializers*.

imgList needs to be static so that it can be used in the CarouselSlider instance

Any solution to fix this?

```
class ImagePreviewPage extends StatefulWidget {
  ImagePreviewPage({Key key, this.templist, this.index}) : super(key: key);
  final List templist;
  final int index;
  bool _isSaving = false;


  @override
  _ImagePreviewPageState createState()  {
    _ImagePreviewPageState();
    }
}

class _ImagePreviewPageState extends State<ImagePreviewPage> {

  @override
  ImagePreviewPage get widget => super.widget;

  static List<String> imgList = widget.templist;
/////////////////Only static members can be accessed in initializers////////////////////


  final CarouselSlider instance = CarouselSlider(
    items: imgList.map((url) {
      return Container(
        margin: EdgeInsets.all(5.0),
        child: ClipRRect(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.all(Radius.circular(5.0)),
            child: Image.network(url,
            fit: BoxFit.cover,
            width: 1000.0,
          )
        )
      );
    }).toList(),
    viewportFraction: 0.9,
    aspectRatio: 2.0,
    autoPlay: true,
  );

  nextSlider() {
    instance.nextPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 300), curve: Curves.linear);
  }

  prevSlider() {
    instance.previousPage(duration: Duration(milliseconds: 800), curve: Curves.easeIn);
  }

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    SystemChrome.setEnabledSystemUIOverlays([]);

  }
```

Answer (score 1):

static List imgList ...

is static, which means it can be accessed without an instance of `_ImagePreviewPageState`.

```
widget.templist
```

references the `widget` property of an `_ImagePreviewPageState`, but there is no instance.

What you could do is

```
class _ImagePreviewPageState extends State<ImagePreviewPage> {
  _ImagePreviewPageState() : super() {
    imgList ??= widget.templist;
  }   

  static List<String> imgList;
```

to get `imgList` initialized the first time such a widget instance is created,
but I doubt that is a good idea because `widget.templist` can vary per widget instance and then it's unlikely to make sense to store that in a static variable.

You'd need to elaborate more about what problem this is supposed to solve to enable others to make concrete suggestions.

Comment: https://pastebin.com/z2cfTjb3

previously I was able to pass a value from the statefulwidget in the Widget build of it's State using widget.url or widget.list. But this doesn't seem to work in any other class or outside Widget build.

Comment: Xou probably didn't use `static` before